# Rails без английского языка

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Хотел спросить - вот хочу начать ( уже начал как бы ) изучать Рельсы.

Может кто посоветовать книги на русском языке или мб сайты - в которых с нуля можно поднимать сайты ( ну чисто для веб ) ( так как по незнанию я только нахожу книги 2007 -2008 года - которые давно устарели )

Понимаю что без англ никак - но хоть начать ( азы ), что б мог создавать странички, ссылки, аутентификацию и т.д. без всяких проблем.

PS rails tutorial уже прочёл
и еще хотел спросить - вообще выучить реилс без англ можно ли ? ( те не читая по 20-40 страниц ) - перевести 10-20 строк я могу как бы

Answer (score 3):

[Railscasts.ru](http://Railscasts.ru), [rusrails.ru](http://rusrails.ru)

Answer (score 1):

[Дэвид Ханссон, «Гибкая разработка веб-приложений в среде Rails»](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9785446101108&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0)

Answer (score 1):

Я - соавтор сайта [rubycourses.ru](http://rubycourses.ru/). Мы, совместно с сообществом, собрали каталог курсов по Ruby и Rails, вместе с отзывами от участников и относительным рейтингом. Есть фильтрация по языку и платности/бесплатности:

- [Бесплатные курсы на русском](http://rubycourses.ru/courses?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&language=%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&paid=0&button=)
- [Платные курсы на русском](http://rubycourses.ru/courses?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&language=%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&paid=1&button=)